# Periodically audit file permissions for mistaken leaks

Tags: linux, security, user-permissions

I'm looking for a way to periodically check a file system tree for permissions that have been set incorrectly.

The context is:

- this is in an academic compute environment, with students, researchers and overworked sysadmins
- the focus is not on malicious actors, but rather mistakes made by any of the above
- existing users/group hierarchy
- prevention does not have to be immediate, we're thinking of something that can run daily
- ideally don't want to have to install extra tools such as tripwire
- don't need a forensic trail to be captured

My hunch is a script that:

- runs daily via cron
- runs as a user with read permissions for the entire tree
- checks that rwx is off for the "all" bits.. (more rules to be added)

Before I start this, is there an established way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You could simply override permissions via `chmod` in a cron script, this way wrong permissions will get changed only. Or an other approach to set permissions is to set a sticky-bit for the parent directory and this will have priority over the file-rights.

Answer (score 3):

You want to check [AIDE](https://aide.github.io/) or
[mtree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fmtree.8.html)

More generic list of [File integrity monitoring software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring)